# Mould and Discoloration of roof tiles near chimney

Tags: roof, chimney

What could be the possible reason(s) for building up of mould / discoloration of the roof tiles near the chimney? What are the DIY / expert solutions to fix this? I am attaching an image of the roof near the chimney area. The house is a semi detached and on the other side of the chimney (neighbour's house) there is no visible mould / discoloration.

[image: roof area near chimney]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That patch actually looks cleaner than the rest, to me, & I see no mould, only moss. They say moss only grows on North faces, but that's not entirely true. It's perhaps remaining wetter for longer than the surrounding area; possibly shaded or in the lee of the prevailing wind.
Check if the rest of the estate shows a similar pattern.

If you're going up to have a proper look, check this flashing too -

[image]

It's hard to tell from this angle but it looks one course short.

Comment: Could be some algae with the moss.

Comment: Could be lichen too… but that would be one for Biology.se ;)